# Can I find out if someone wants a read confirmation of an email by examinig the header?

Tags: email

Can I find out if someone wants a read confirmation of an email by examinig the header?

Where can I find this info or string and how is it called?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you look for the header `Disposition-Notification-To:`, that indicates a read receipt is required, the data on the header indicates the account the receipt goes to.